# Custom delimiter doesn't work in CsvHelper

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I'm using CsvHelper v26.1.0 to read the following text file delimited by `~`:

```
123~John
234~Joe "Public"
```

But the double quotes in the file is causing CsvHelper to treat them as bad data. I tested it by removing the double quotes and it worked fine. But the question is, I already set a custom delimiter, why is the double quote still causing the problem?

```
public class AccountDtoMap : ClassMap<AccountDto>
{
    public AccountDtoMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Number).Index(0);
        Map(m => m.Name).Index(1);
    }
}

var cfg = new CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    Delimiter = "~",
    HasHeaderRecord = false,
    MissingFieldFound = (context) => { errs.Add($"{typeof(T)} missing field: {context.Context.Parser.RawRecord}"); },
    BadDataFound = (context) => { errs.Add($"{typeof(T)} bad data: {context.RawRecord}"); },
};

using (var csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(file), cfg))
{
    csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<AccountDtoMap>();
    return csv.GetRecords<T>().ToList();
}
```

Runnable demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4LXqa8).

Comment: Double quote is the character CsvHelper uses to quote (encapsulate) fields. Try either doubling up the double quotes (e.g. `""Public""`), or changing the quote character

Comment: @greenjaed Tried to double up the quotes but still got that same error.

Comment: Sorry, my advice was incomplete. Try quoting the entire field and then doubling the double quotes.

Comment: You may be confusing the delimiter with the [`Escape`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/CsvConfiguration.cs#L58) and/or [`Quote`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/CsvConfiguration.cs#L126) settings.  If your cells contain embedded escape characters you may need to escape the entire cell as per [RFC 4180 2.7](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180#page-2)

Comment: @greenjaed Thank you, I got it now, but I can't change the source file and correcting it will be too much work.

Comment: @dbc After changing both Escape and Quote chars to `\t`, it worked. I'm very sure the source file won't have tabs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To parse the CSV shown in your question (in version [26.1.0](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/releases/tag/26.1.0)), you need to properly configure all of the following [`CsvConfiguration`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/CsvConfiguration.cs#L58) settings, not just the delimiter:

- [`Delimiter`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/CsvConfiguration.cs#L46).  The character used to **delimit** fields in a single CSV line.  (Usually `,`, here `~`).
- [`Escape`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/CsvConfiguration.cs#L58), default `"`.  The character used to **precede** some other character that needs escaping.
- [`Quote`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/CsvConfiguration.cs#L126), default `"`.  The character used to **wrap** a field that needs quotes at the beginning and end as per [RFC4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#page-2).
- [`Mode`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/CsvConfiguration.cs#L106).  The [`CsvMode`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/CsvMode.cs) to use when parsing and writing.

The function of the first three character settings above is explained in the comments for the [`CsvMode` enum](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/CsvMode.cs):

```
public enum CsvMode
{
    /// Uses RFC 4180 format (default).
    /// If a field contains a CsvConfiguration.Delimiter or CsvConfiguration.NewLine,
    /// it is wrapped in CsvConfiguration.Quote's.
    /// If quoted field contains a CsvConfiguration.Quote, it is preceded by CsvConfiguration.Escape.
    RFC4180 = 0,

    /// Uses escapes.
    /// If a field contains a CsvConfiguration.Delimiter, CsvConfiguration.NewLine,
    /// or CsvConfiguration.Escape, it is preceded by CsvConfiguration.Escape.
    /// Newline defaults to \n.
    Escape,

    /// <summary>
    /// Doesn't use quotes or escapes.
    /// This will ignore quoting and escape characters. This means a field cannot contain a
    /// CsvConfiguration.Delimiter, CsvConfiguration.Quote, or
    /// CsvConfiguration.NewLine, as they cannot be escaped.
    NoEscape
}
```

The field `Joe "Public"` contains embedded escape characters that are not themselves escaped, which is causing CshHelper to report an error. In order to avoid the error, you have several possible options including:

1. Set `CsvMode.NoEscape` to completely disable escaping and quoting:

   ```
   var cfg = new CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
   {
       Mode = CsvMode.NoEscape,
       // Remainder unchanged.
   ```

   Of course, if you do this, your CSV file **cannot** contain delimiters or newlines embedded in fields.

   Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NgJA6o).
2. Set `Mode = CsvMode.Escape` to disable wrapping of fields in quotes, and set `Escape` to some other character such as `\` or `\t` that you do not expect to encounter in the file in practice:

   ```
   var cfg = new CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
   {
       Mode = CsvMode.Escape,
       Escape = '\\',
       // Remainder unchanged.
   ```

   Even if you do this, delimiters, escape and newline characters inside CSV fields must still be properly escaped using the selected escape character.

   Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yuYJvJ).
3. Set `Mode = CsvMode.Escape` and fix your file to properly escape the escape characters:

   ```
   234~Joe ""Public""
   ```

   Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Llz8zx).