# Using CSVHelper to parse a pipe deliminated file with quotes in the content

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, csvhelper

I have an externally generated pipe deliminated file which I am trying to parse using .NET CSVHelper and enter into a SQL database but am finding a problem. The main issue is that there's quotes in the content but the delimiter is pipe and the quotes aren't escaped.

Imagine this being the file

```
ID|Price|Description|stock

133|55.89|Standard Electric Drill|23

134|3.40|3.5" Drill Bit|56
```

I've set the deliminater to pipe but it errors when it reaches a record with the quote ( in this case ID 134 with the quote " denoting inch) in the description. The error suggests setting BadDataFound to Null but that would just ignore the record?

Is there any configuration that I've missed that would allow this? Or is the best way simply to replace quotes with {quote} or something, parse it and then replace back before entering it into the database?

Comment: You have to tell CsvReader that the text fields are *not* quoted. Which version are you using though? CsvHelper releases a new major version with breaking changes every other month.

Comment: For example, in v. 21.3 one of the changes was `Added back Excel compatibility for bad data fallback.
If a field doesn't start with a Quote, read until a Delimiter or NewLine is found.`. Sounds like what you encountered

Comment: I'm using 27.0.1, only downloaded a couple of days ago...I noticed that there's lots of configuration changes which don't work when I looked on forums etc.

Comment: Another thing that changed recently was the configuration `Mode` property which controls  [how CSV files are handled](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/0d753ff09294b425e4bc5ab346145702eeeb1b6f/src/CsvHelper/CsvMode.cs#L12) - escaped, unescaped or using the RFC settings. The default RFC setting *doesn't* allow a quote in the middle of the field without escaping

Comment: As I said, CsvHelper uses frequent major versions as an excuse to introduce breaking changes. Class names change, new ones appear, properties move from one type to another. Upgrading is always a risk. I found about the `Mode` the same way you did - after an upgrade, existing code broke without explanation

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Custom delimiter doesn't work in CsvHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66824728/3744182).  Agree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NoEscape` mode should work as long as no field contains a pipe or newline character.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        Mode = CsvMode.NoEscape,
        Delimiter = "|"
    };
    
    using (var reader = new StringReader("ID|Price|Description|stock\n133|55.89|Standard Electric Drill|23\n134|3.40|3.5\" Drill Bit|56"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().Dump();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int stock { get; set; }
}
```