# Ignore delimiter within quote CsvHelper

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I am trying to read in a comma delimited csv file which, for the most part are not text qualified unless fields include a comma.  An example of this would be an address line that could include a comma.  When that happens, the columns are shunted within my mapped object.

```
AddressLine1, Email, ID
House Name, test@test.net, 5
"House Name, 20", test@test.net,5
```

Ignoring bad results, this results in the objects

```
[0] AddressLine1: House Name, Email: test@test.net, ID: 5
[1] AddressLine1: House Name, Email: 20, ID: test@test.net
```

I've tried various configurations including amending the mode and escape characters.

```
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
HasHeaderRecord = true,
  Delimiter = ",",                    
  HeaderValidated = null,
  Mode = CsvMode.Escape,
  Escape = '\\'
};
```

Can someone help point me in the right direction please?

Comment: You should use another delimiter character like `;`

Comment: Hi, I don't have control of the files coming in so have to work with what I've got.

Comment: That sounds like something else is going wrong. CsvHelper should already do what you require by default. Maybe check for extra quotes in your data or a setting CsvHelper to ignore quotes somewhere? See : https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/825

Comment: Very odd - I tried the same code on another machine and it worked fine as you suggested.  I'll investigate further...

Answer (score 5):

Since the field `"House Name, 20"` is wrapped in quotes, you should set `CsvConfiguration.Mode` to `CsvMode.CsvMode.RFC4180`  This [enum](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/CsvMode.cs) is defined as follows:

```
public enum CsvMode
{
    /// Uses RFC 4180 format (default).
    /// If a field contains a CsvConfiguration.Delimiter or CsvConfiguration.NewLine,
    /// it is wrapped in CsvConfiguration.Quote's.
    /// If quoted field contains a CsvConfiguration.Quote, it is preceded by CsvConfiguration.Escape.
    RFC4180 = 0,

    /// Uses escapes.
    /// If a field contains a CsvConfiguration.Delimiter, CsvConfiguration.NewLine,
    /// or CsvConfiguration.Escape, it is preceded by CsvConfiguration.Escape.
    /// Newline defaults to \n.
    Escape,

    /// <summary>
    /// Doesn't use quotes or escapes.
    /// This will ignore quoting and escape characters. This means a field cannot contain a
    /// CsvConfiguration.Delimiter, CsvConfiguration.Quote, or
    /// CsvConfiguration.NewLine, as they cannot be escaped.
    NoEscape
}
```

Since the header fields  `Email` and  `ID` are preceded by spaces you may also want to set `TrimOptions = TrimOptions.Trim`.  Thus your `CsvConfiguration` should look like:

```
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    HasHeaderRecord = true,
    // Delimiter = ",", This is the default so no need to change
    HeaderValidated = null,
    Mode = CsvMode.RFC4180,
    TrimOptions = TrimOptions.Trim,
};
```

Related: *[Custom delimiter doesn't work in CsvHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66824728/3744182)*.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KHE5Nu).