# How to write unescaped quoted values

Tags: c#, .net, csv, csvhelper

Does CsvHelper not support quoted unescaped output or is there something wrong with my writer configuration?

Input:

```
Jake|"B" Street
```

CsvHelper reader configuration:

```
var readerConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    Delimiter = "|",
    TrimOptions = TrimOptions.Trim,     
    IgnoreBlankLines = true,
    Mode = CsvMode.NoEscape
};
```

After record is read into memory, the value with double quotes is unescaped as expected: `"B" Street`

However, when I write records to CSV file if `ShouldQuote = args => true` is used without `CsvMode.NoEscape` double quotes are escaped and if I add `CsvMode.NoEscape` the output is not quoted at all.

```
writerConfiguration = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    ShouldQuote = args => true,
    Mode = CsvMode.NoEscape
};
```

Output with `CsvMode.NoEscape`: `"B" Street` // Output not quoted and not escaped.

Output without `CsvMode.NoEscape`: `"""B"" Street"` // Double quotes escaped.

Any ideas on how to write unescaped quoted values with CsvHelper?

Comment: I don't believe there is a setting to quote but not escape.  `CsvMode.NoEscape` overrides the `ShouldQuote`.

Comment: @DavidSpecht Thanks, but isn't this a valid scenario for output and if so what is the proper way of asking Josh to implement this? His GitHub page?

Comment: I this a duplicate of [Custom delimiter doesn't work in CsvHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72198080/3744182)?  If not, could you share a full [mcve]?

Comment: I can't see a problem with your current configuration.  I am able to round-trip `Jake|"B" Street` successfully, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/wwWSrv.  Can you share a [mcve] showing the exact CSV you want to generate?

Comment: @dbc Thanks for your effort, here is my example (note I am using CsvHelper 28.0.1 if of any significance) https://dotnetfiddle.net/itHz0P

Comment: @DeanKuga It depends on what you mean by valid scenario.  It's not valid according to [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180.html) "If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with another double quote."  `NoEscape` was developed to deal with _reading_ improperly formatted CSV.  I don't believe Josh Close ever planned on _outputting_ malformed CSV.  If, however, you have a good reason for it, then yes, I would submit a ticket on his [GitHub page](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels a little hacky, but I was able to do what I think you are trying to do with `CsvMode.NoEscape` and a custom string converter to add the outer quotes. Another option would be to use `Convert` in a `ClassMap` to add the outer quotes on a column by column basis.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var records = new List<Foo>
    {
        new Foo { Id = 1, Name = "\"B\" Street" },
    };
    
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        Mode = CsvMode.NoEscape
    };

    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, config))
    {
        csv.Context.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<string>(new OuterQuoteConverter());
        csv.WriteRecords(records);
    }
}

public class OuterQuoteConverter : StringConverter
{
    public override string ConvertToString(object value, IWriterRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        var quoted = "\"" + (string)value + "\"";
        return base.ConvertToString(quoted, row, memberMapData);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually works great, I was not aware that CsvHelper was extensible in that way as I'm not using the library frequently. When I'm done with the current project I'll submit a question on CsvHelper GitHub page and hopefully Josh will consider adding the ability to generate quoted unescaped output...