# How do I preserve unescaped double quotes in TSV data?

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I have unescaped double quotes in my TSV (tab-separated values) data and I want to preserve them while reading with CsvHelper. For example:

```
Column1    Column2    Column3
Value "1"  Value "2"  Value "3"
```

How do I do it? Right now my `CsvConfiguration` looks like that:

```
new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    HasHeaderRecord = true,
    Delimiter = "/t",
    NewLine = "/r/n",
    IgnoreBlankLines = true,
    MissingFieldFound = null,
    HeaderValidated = null,
    CacheFields = true,
    PrepareHeaderForMatch = args => args.Header.Trim(),
    TrimOptions = TrimOptions.Trim,
    LineBreakInQuotedFieldIsBadData = false,
            
};
```

I could set `BadDataFound = null` but since `Value "2"` is not considered bad I'm not sure if this is a valid option.

Comment: You state that you have *TSV (tab-separated values) data* however the text you posted **does not contain any tab `\t` characters**, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/OFYIhZ.  `Regex.Matches(csvString, "\t").Count` is zero. Might you please confirm that you really have a TSV file and not a [fixed-width text file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/drives-directories-files/how-to-read-from-fixed-width-text-files), and if so, [edit] your post to include actual sample TSV text?  `CsvHelper` is not the best choice for reading fixed width text files.

Comment: That being said, since `"` is the default character used for escaping and quoting of fields, setting `CsvConfiguration.Mode = CsvMode.NoEscape` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66832869/3744182) to [Custom delimiter doesn't work in CsvHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66824728/3744182) might solve your problem.  A [mcve] would clarify.

Comment: Also, you are escaping the tab, carriage return and newline characters wrongly in your string literals.  You need to use a backslash not a forward slash.  See the doc page [Quoted String Literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#quoted-string-literals) for the syntax.  Your code should look like `Delimiter = "\t", NewLine = "\r\n"`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/JWjg7h (before) and https://dotnetfiddle.net/vPNWrk (after).

Answer (score 1):

The **TSV, Tab-Separated Values** text file format is defined by the Library of Congress [as follows](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000533.shtml):

> A tab-separated values (TSV) file is a text format whose primary function is to store data in a table structure where each record in the table is recorded as one line of the text file. The field’s values in the record are separated by tab characters. Header rows may provide information about the semantics of table columns.
>
> ... Field values cannot contain tabs or new line characters so conversion of plain text to TSV requires the following escapes (with parenthetical corresponding ASCII codes):
>
> `\n` for newline (ascii 0x0a)
>
> `\t` for tab (ascii 0x09)
>
> `\r` for carriage return (ASCII 0x0d)
>
> `\\` for backslash (ASCII 0x5c)

You may easily make CsvHelper use a Tab character as a delimiter by setting [`CsvConfiguration.Delimiter = "\t"`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/CsvConfiguration.cs#L47), however the escaping specified by the LoC does not correspond to any of the [escaping modes](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/CsvMode.cs) supported by CsvHelper. Thus you will need to

1. Set [`CsvConfiguration.Mode = CsvMode.NoEscape`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/CsvConfiguration.cs#L119) to disable escaping by CsvHelper.
2. Write your own [custom type converter](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/type-conversion/custom-type-converter/) for `string` that handles escaping manually, then register it globally.

First define the following [`ITypeConverter`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/c411801f4cbb04100711016c8fa2e7cf894433f2/src/CsvHelper/TypeConversion/ITypeConverter.cs) and extension methods:

```
public class TSVStringConverter : CsvHelper.TypeConversion.StringConverter
{
    public static TSVStringConverter Instance { get; } = new TSVStringConverter();

    static ReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>> EscapeMap = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            //https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000533.shtml
            //The order here is important, the \\ must come first.
            { new("\\", "\\\\") },
            { new("\n", "\\n") },
            { new("\t", "\\t") },
            { new("\r", "\\r") },
        }.AsReadOnly();

    public override string ConvertToString(object value, IWriterRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        if (value is string s)
            value = EscapeMap.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(s), (sb, p) => sb.Replace(p.Key, p.Value)).ToString();
        return base.ConvertToString(value, row, memberMapData);
    }

    public override object ConvertFromString(string text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        var obj = base.ConvertFromString(text, row, memberMapData);
        if (obj is string s)
            obj = EscapeMap.Reverse().Aggregate(new StringBuilder(s), (sb, p) => sb.Replace(p.Value, p.Key)).ToString();
        return obj;
    }
}   

public static class CsvHelperExtensions
{
    public static CsvConfiguration SetupTSV(this CsvConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Delimiter = "\t"; // FIXED
        config.NewLine = "\r\n"; // FIXED
        config.Mode = CsvMode.NoEscape; // ADDED
        config.LineBreakInQuotedFieldIsBadData = true; // Changed false => true as per LoC requirement
        return config;
    }
    
    public static CsvContext SetupTSV(this CsvContext context)
    {
        context.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<string>(TSVStringConverter.Instance);
        return context;
    }
}
```

And now, if your record model looks like e.g.

```
public record Model(string Column1, string Column2, string Column3);
```

You will be able to deserialize a TSV string as follows:

```
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    HasHeaderRecord = true,
    IgnoreBlankLines = true,
    MissingFieldFound = null,
    HeaderValidated = null,
    CacheFields = true,
    PrepareHeaderForMatch = args => args.Header.Trim(),
    TrimOptions = TrimOptions.Trim, 
    //LineBreakInQuotedFieldIsBadData = false, REMOVED
}
.SetupTSV(); // Add TSV specific options

using (var reader = new StringReader(tsvString)) // Or use a StreamReader when reading from a file
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
{
    csv.Context.SetupTSV(); // Add TSV string converter for escaping and unescaping
    // Register your class map here if needed.
    
    var newRecords = csv.GetRecords<Model>().ToList();
}
```

Notes:

- In your question, you are escaping the tab, carriage return and newline characters wrongly in your string literals. As explained in the documentation page [Quoted String Literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#quoted-string-literals), you need to use a backslash not a forward slash.  Thus your code should have looked like

  ```
  Delimiter = "\t", 
  NewLine = "\r\n",
  ```
- The TSV text in your question does not actually include any Tab characters.  I will assume that is a typo in the question created during formatting. If your TSV data does not contain any Tabs, then it is not a TSV file at all, and you should look into [fixed width text file parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/drives-directories-files/how-to-read-from-fixed-width-text-files).
- See the [IANA Registration for TSV](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/tab-separated-values) for a formal definition of the TSV grammar.
- See *[Custom delimiter doesn't work in CsvHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66824728/3744182)* for a description of the various CsvHelper options related to escaping, quoting and delimiting.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ml0BkR).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CsvMode.NoEscape`. It just means you won't be able to have line breaks or tabs inside any of your fields.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        HasHeaderRecord = true,
        Delimiter = "\t",
        NewLine = "\r\n",
        IgnoreBlankLines = true,
        MissingFieldFound = null,
        HeaderValidated = null,
        CacheFields = true,
        PrepareHeaderForMatch = args => args.Header.Trim(),
        TrimOptions = TrimOptions.Trim,
        LineBreakInQuotedFieldIsBadData = false,
        Mode = CsvMode.NoEscape
    };

    using (var reader = new StringReader("Column1\tColumn2\tColumn3\r\nValue \"1\"\tValue \"2\"\tValue \"3\""))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().Dump();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public string Column1 { get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
    public string Column3 { get; set; }
}
```