# Pointing to specific header in csvhelper

Tags: c#, csvhelper

My csv file reads 2 columns, and I want to be move a header into data. I have no control over this csv file, otherwise I would manipulate it.

```
Characteristics:
Appearance:,Null
Type:,Null
Dopant:,Null
Diameter:,Null
Resistivity:,Null
Thickness:,Null
Primary Flat Length:,Null
Secondary Flat Length:,NA
Primary Flat Position:,Null5
Orientation:,Null
Si Face:,Null
C Face:,Null
```

I want to move the 'null' column down underneath the 'Type' column, the null column is the data for the type.

I want it to look like

```
Characteristics:
Appearance:,
Null
Type:,
Null
Dopant:,
Null
Diameter:,
Null
Resistivity:,
Null
Thickness:,
Null
Primary Flat Length:,
Null
Secondary Flat Length:,
NA
Primary Flat Position:,
Null5
Orientation:,
Null
Si Face:,
Null
C Face:,
Null
```

or perhaps

```
Characteristics:Appearance:,Type:,Dopant:,Diameter:,Resistivity:,Thickness:,Primary Flat Length:,Secondary Flat Length:,Primary Flat Position:,Orientation:,Si Face:,C Face:,
Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null,Null,
```

basically I'm trying to make the null column go underneath the type column, making 2 columns into 1.
any suggestions?

I tried using the Prepare header for match idea but it did not work as I intended.

```
PrepareHeaderForMatch = header => Regex.Replace("null", "\n")
```

Or if I can get all of the headers, appearance, type, dopant, etc, all in a row, that would be more practical, but again I have no control over ANY data in the csv.
I know this is an extremely niche and weird case that I'm unsure if this can be manipulated in this way, but any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Maybe there is a way to point to a specific header in the header row?

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share before-and-after CSV samples?  As it is it's not quite clear what you want.  Are you saying you want to transform a two-column CSV file to a one-column CSV file with the values of the `null` column being added under the `Type` column?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm going for, making 2 collumns into 1

Comment: OK, but can you share before-and-after CSV samples?  E.g. are there headers, or not?  Do you want to overwrite the values in the `Type` column, or interleave them somehow?

Comment: As of right now, both type, and null are headers, my issue is that null is the data I need. I need Type to be the header, and null to be the data underneath the Type header. There no other data in the Type collumn, just null.

Comment: Use CsvHelper's `CsvReader` to read each line as a record with two properties, then take the two values from that record and add each to the result list.

Comment: Include actual samples in your question. Also explain which parts of this csv you have no control over.

Comment: done, I'm wondering if maybe there is a way to make the headings all go in their own row, with the nulls underneath

Comment: This looks like a terrible idea. The result wouldn't even really be CSV anymore.

Comment: Honestly you may be overthinking this.  Does the input file actually use any of the [escaping modes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66832869) for commas or newlines embedded in cells?  If not, simply reading line-by-line and doing `string.Replace(",", ",\n")` might be the simplest way to get what you need.

Comment: I'm well aware of that, open to any other solutions, the customer providing this information is not the brightest at giving information that is easy to work with.

Comment: The input is far easier to work with than the proposed output, though neither is great. What I'd really want to do is pivot the other direction: instead of more rows collapse it down to fewer, with more headers, so each separate record is one row. Maybe it would help if you shared what you want to do with this data after you have changed it. Or, if there's more in the file before or after this text, share that as well.

Comment: my problem with the input is that it's reading 'null' as a header when in reality it's data, so if I don't have to reorganize it, then I would much rather prefer that, I just thought making that change to 1 column would work. I need to export this data into a datatable so I can input it into MongoDB, There isn't more to the file, just another block of data similar to this one. Yeah condensing things down to fewer rows would be nice, I just don't know how to do that.

Comment: Where did the input file come from?  Excel?  That would tell us whether, and how, embedded commas are escaped, which would in turn indicate whether CSV readers and writers are required.

Comment: Yes the files came from excel and was converted into csv

Comment: What output do you want for the *or perhaps* case?

Comment: Where all of the headers are shifted up into 1 row and the data is all underneath in the row below. Trying to make a list that can be converted to a datatable (which I can do that part). Like how Joel was saying, collapse the data into less rows rather than expand into more rows.

Comment: Is this what you need?  https://dotnetfiddle.net/yyzw5p.  It produces the required output for the first case, but since you don't share required output for the second case I can't be sure it's working as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the original data format is pretty easy to read.  The first line appears to be the table name and each line after that appears to be the column name followed by if it allows null.  Why not just make a class with properties of `Type` and `Value`.  The first record will have your table name and the rest will have the column names.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        HasHeaderRecord = false,
        MissingFieldFound = null
    };
    
    using (var reader = new StringReader("Characteristics:\nAppearance:,Null\nType:,Null\nDopant:,Null"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        var records = csv.GetRecords<TableData>().ToList();
        
        var table = records[0];
        
        records.RemoveAt(0);
        
        var columns = records;
        
        table.Dump();
        columns.Dump();
    }
}

public class TableData
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

[image: Table Values]

You could also use your `TableData` records to pivot the data as @JoelCoehoorn suggested

```cs
void Main()
{
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        HasHeaderRecord = false,
        MissingFieldFound = null
    };
    
    using (var reader = new StringReader("Characteristics:\nAppearance:,Null\nType:,Null\nDopant:,Null"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        var records = csv.GetRecords<TableData>().ToList();
        
        using (var writer = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            writer.WriteField(records[0].Type);
            writer.NextRecord();
            
            records.RemoveAt(0);
            
            foreach (var item in records.Select(r => r.Type))
            {
                writer.WriteField(item);
            }
            writer.NextRecord();
            
            foreach (var item in records.Select(r => r.Value))
            {
                writer.WriteField(item);
            }
            writer.NextRecord();
        }
    }

}

public class TableData
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```